# Selecting From a Question Pool (Combination Question)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

> Alice is taking her probability exam tomorrow and she will be assigned  5 questions out of a pool
> consisting of  13 questions. In​ particular, the pool includes  5 ​easy, 2 ​medium, and 6 difficult
> questions.
>
> If 5 questions are selected at random at the beginning of the​ exam, find the probability that Alice
> will be​ assigned: both of the medium questions and at least 1 difficult question.

I've been trying hard to find a solution to this question but I couldn't. Here is what I did,

(nCr(2,2) * nCr(6,1))/nCr(13, 5) + (nCr(2,2) * nCr(6,2))/nCr(13, 5) + ... + (nCr(2,2) *
nCr(6,6))/nCr(13, 5) = 0.04895

But it turned out to be wrong, what am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are not selecting remaining questions from easy. Pls see my answer.

Comment: I have changed your code block to a quote block. What you were doing has the drawback of being terrible for screen readers: it tells them to assume the text is code, not words, and read it letter by letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total number of unrestricted selections of $5$ questions $ = \displaystyle {13 \choose 5} = 1287$

Total number of possible selections where both medium questions are selected and at least one difficult question is selected
$\displaystyle = {11 \choose 3} - {5 \choose 3} = 155$

So the desired probability $ = \displaystyle \frac{155}{1287}$.

**In your working**, you also need to select remaining questions from easy. So it should be $\displaystyle \small \bigg[{6 \choose 1}{5 \choose 2} + {6 \choose 2} {5 \choose 1} + {6 \choose 3}\bigg] \bigg/ {13 \choose 5}$

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help, I get it now @MathLover